# Gtk.TextView not displaying changes made to buffer via popup menu (Python)

Tags: python, textview, popup, gtk, contextmenu

I am trying to customize the popup of a Gtk.TextView. I want the user to be able to select a misspelled word, right-click on it, and then have a list of possible correct spellings added to the popup. When the user makes his or her selection, the chosen menu item's label is inserted in place of the textview's selected text. The problem is that the textview refuses to display the changes. Even the built-in cut, copy, and paste menu items aren't working.

For example, if add this line to **init**:

```
self.textview.connect("populate-popup", self.display_spelling_options)
```

And then add these functions:

```
def display_spelling_options(self, textview, popup):
    mi = Gtk.MenuItem.new_with_label("Example")
    mi.connect("activate", self.menu_choice)
    popup.append(mi)
    popup.show_all()

def menu_choice(self, widget):
    buf = self.textview.get_buffer()
    buf.set_text("Hello, World")
    self.textview.show_all() #This line makes no difference
```

Or if I make any other changes to the buffer, the textview does not display the changes. The changes are written to the buffer (I verified that by adding a get_text() to the end of menu_choice), but the textview does not redraw itself to display the buffer's changes. Yet it does redraw itself if I call menu_choice from a widget other than the popup. Why is the textview not responding if the popup is used?

Comment: ***"the textview does not redraw"***: Works for me as expected, the whole text are replaced and the `TextView` redraws `"Hello World"`, even without `.show_all()`. There must be another fault, [edit] your Question and extend to a [mcve].

Comment: Furthermore, a [Gtk.Spell](http://gtkspell.sourceforge.net/) instance will accomplish all you are trying to do.